# If I increment the first tryte of Seed A to obtain Seed B, why does Seed B retain some of the spent addresses of Seed A in it's history?

Tags: seed, legacy-protocol, ternary

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=88&v=olOgzNWJk8Q) when you take a Seed A (e.g. HIJK99) and increment the first tryte by one to obtain another Seed B (i.e. IIJK99), Seed B is associated to the transactions to Seed A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every new address is generated by incrementing a seed and doing some hashing. This gives a useful feature: If you don't want to see the whole history of the transfers then increment the seed before entering it into wallet software and transactions associated with the very first address won't be shown (this process can be repeated).

The feature may work improperly if your seed has several inputs, so make sure that your balance doesn't become lower this way.

Comment: When generating an address is only the first tryte incremented and hashed? Or is the entire 81 trytes incremented and hashed?

Comment: Entire 81-tryte seed is incremented which usually changes only a single tryte (like 11:45:27 >> 11:45:28), sometimes several trytes are changed (like 08:59:59 >> 09:00:00).